# What do we know about the connection between SARS-CoV-2 and meat plants?

Tags: covid-19, hygiene, virus

In the last days we get news from all over the world that "meat plants" are severely hit by Covid-19 outbreaks (Ireland, Poland, Canada, US). We also know that the "wet market" in Wuhan played a crucial role  in the initial phase of the pandemics.

So my question is:

> Is there anything in "meat plants" where the virus can (very?) efficiently replicate? E.g. Animal (cow/pig/chicken) blood? Organ tissue, ...? Is that being under investigantion, currently?

Comment: Welcome to Medical Sciences! Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. For [reasons mentioned in this post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411) and in [ask], we require some degree of prior research when asking questions. *See [this list of helpful resources](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/784)*. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, what made you ask this question, and any problems you are having understanding your research. If you found nothing, what did you Google?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does the SARS-CoV-2 (Novel Coronavirus) live longer in a fridge or freezer?](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/23250/does-the-sars-cov-2-novel-coronavirus-live-longer-in-a-fridge-or-freezer)

Comment: Meat processing/packing plants are places where many people work in very close proximity on an assembly line, in an industry deemed essential so that they are still in full operation despite many other businesses being closed. It doesn't take anything more special than that.

Comment: I think this is an important question, but it still lacks any effort at prior research despite my prior request. You ask if the issue is being investigated. Well, I believe it is, and I'm pretty sure there are readily available articles on that subject. Would you please link to one or two? That's all that's being asked of you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There have been suspicions for a long time that meat processing plants are just plain unhealthy due to poor hygiene as well as likely aerosolizing animal viruses which are then inhaled by meat processing workers.  This suggests that these places are unable to protect workers from air borne viruses

> **Results:** An excess of deaths from cancers of the base of the tongue, esophagus, lung, skin, bone and bladder, lymphoid leukemia, and benign tumors of the thyroid and other endocrine glands, and possibly Hodgkin's disease, was observed in abattoir and meat processing workers. Significantly lower SMRs were recorded for cancer of the thymus, mediastinum, pleura, etc., breast cancer, and non-Hodgkin's lymphoma.
>
> **Conclusion:** This study confirms the excess occurrence of cancer in workers in abattoirs and meat processing plants, butchers, and meatcutters, previously reported in this cohort and other similar cohorts worldwide. Large nested case-control studies are now needed to examine which specific occupational and non-occupational exposures are responsible for the excess. There is now sufficient evidence for steps to be taken to protect workers from carcinogenic exposures at the workplace. There are also serious implications for the general population which may also be exposed to some of these viruses.

With respect to SARS-CoV-2 the work environment in meat processing plants is also allowing this virus to be easily transmitted between workers.

> Roughly half a million people work in the nation's meat processing industry, and crowded and unsanitary conditions have prompted concerns about worker safety during the coronavirus pandemic. As of April 27, 4,913 meat and poultry plant workers in 115 plants in 19 states had been diagnosed with COVID-19, the disease caused by the coronavirus, and 20 people had died, according to the report from the Centers for Disease Control and Prevention. In 17 states that provided data on how many workers were employed at affected facilities, 3% of more than 130,000 workers were diagnosed with COVID-19, researchers found.

with apparent differences between plants

> The share of workers who were infected with COVID-19 ranged from about 1% at affected plants in states like Kansas, Missouri and North Carolina – where 106, 36 and 166 workers were ill, respectively – to about 18% in Iowa, where 377 people tested positive and data on deaths was unavailable.

The virus is fastidious and needs to be grown in special cell cultures.  To grow in the wild it really needs a living host and it's hard to imagine that it would readily grow on animal carcasses.

Cancer Mortality in Workers Employed in Cattle, Pigs, and Sheep Slaughtering and Processing Plants
https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/21497401/

https://www.usnews.com/news/healthiest-communities/articles/2020-05-01/cdc-nearly-5-000-meat-plant-workers-infected-by-coronavirus